# Is it possible to keep some cookies from the opened but completely unresponsive Chrome incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, chromium, incognito-mode

I have an curent opened incognito window that complet frozen(no respond, black screen, even exit buttons are dead) is there a easy or hardcore way to extract sesion cookies or cache to insert after pc reboot and continue a logined sesion?

Chrome's built-in task manager opens but is white blank.
Using desktop icon opens new window but also full black.